# Collapse multiple columns into single row with maximum value from each column?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have something like this

```
df <- data.frame(row1 = c(1, 2), row2 = c(3, 1), row3 = c(1, 4))
```

and I want to collapse the columns keeping only the maximum value from each row such that df is a single row containing 2, 3, 4. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
df %>% dplyr::summarise_all(max)

#   row1 row2 row3
# 1    2    3    4
```

Comment: @mowglis_diaper, perhaps, but it feels like cheating when this is a duplicate with much better quality answers than my own

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, max))
#   row1 row2 row3                                                               
# 1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, max)]
```

**Result:**

```
   row1 row2 row3
1:    2    3    4
```